# Adding a class to a created element

Tags: javascript

The parameter of my function is a function. It should create an element but I should still be able to add attributes by using the parameter `details`.

E.g.:

```js
const addElement = (details) => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
}

addElement(function() {
    element.id = 'my-div'; // Not working since element is not defined
});
```

Well, I have tried to store the element in an object to be able to use it outside of that function.

```js
let element = {};
const displayVideo = (type, details) => {
    element = document.createElement(type);
    element.width = 200;
    element.height = 200;
    element.classList.add('my-class'); // <--- THE PROBLEM!
    if (details) {
        details();
    }
    document.querySelector('#layer').insertBefore(element, document.querySelector('#el'));
};

displayVideo('VIDEO', function () {
    element.controls = true;
});
```

My element can not be created because of `element.classList.add('my-class');` and I don't even get an error message. If I remove that line, it works but I would still like to be able to add a class to that object. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please add a [mre]?

Comment: Pass the element to the function…!? `details(element)`, and `addElement(function (element) { ... })`.

Comment: One weird trick to avoid bugs and help avoid brittle design: don't access external data from inside a function, especially global data, and especially don't mutate it. Treat funcs as black boxes that take input and give output. Bonus points if you don't mutate any of the parameters either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `element` into the function. Since you're just editing properties on the object, this won't cause reference vs value errors.

```js
const addElement = (details) => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    if (details) details(element);
    return element;
}

const ele = addElement(function(element) {
    element.id = 'my-div';
});

console.log(ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `details` could be something like `classname`.

```
function element(type, classname) {

    var element = document.createElement(type);
    
    if (classname !== undefined) {
        element.classList.add(classname);
    }
    
    return element;
};

element("div","my-class"); //<div class="my-class"></div>
```

Of course instead of `classname` you could use an array or an object and loop through in order to set multiple attributes.

Or you could store the return value of your function in a variable and then add all the attributes:

```
var myelement = element("div");
myelement.classList.add("my-new-class");
myelement //<div class=​"my-new-class">​</div>​
```